# Linux Team Explorer specify line ending (LF)

Tags: linux, tfs

We use the same source code in both Windows and Linux.

I've installed Team Explorer Everywhere plugin to Eclipse in CentOS 7. But when I get the files, they all get the Windows file ending (LFCR).

How to force line endings for all files to be LF (or OS default)? I don't want to make dos2unix for every file in every directory.. (I guess I should use tpattributes somehow, but I don't understand how.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check [Extended Attributes in Team Explorer Everywhere](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsxp/archive/2010/04/26/extended-attributes-in-team-explorer-everywhere.aspx). A string pair attribute that enables automatic conversion of line endings to the named style when a file is written to a working folder during a "get" operation.

When this attribute is set for a file, all line styles of line endings are converted to the named style. Only set this attribute for text files in encodings supported by your Java runtime.